# Send email to address from form input

Tags: php, email

I have a pretty standard contact form with inputs for name, email address and phone number. As well as sending the email to the specified email address as per a standard form,

```
$to      = 'diysoakwells@hotmail.com';
```

I would also like to send the email to the user using the address from the email address input from the form. I was thinking using the post variable from the email input like this would work:

```
$to      = 'diysoakwells@hotmail.com', $email;
```

but no luck. Can someone point me in the right directiona and are there any security risks in using this approach? I ultimately aim to provide the user with a checkbox that if checked sends a copy of the email to themselves.

Here is a link to my form

http://www.diysoakwells.com.au/cart.php

Thankyou in advance : )

```
<?php
include_once("wsp_captcha.php");

if(WSP_CheckImageCode() != "OK") {
header('location:/form-rejected.php');
die();
}
$to      = 'diysoakwells@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'Order Inquiry';
$jcitems = " <p><b>ORDER:</b></p><p> " . $_POST['jcitems']."<p/>" . "<p><b>Total:</b> $" . $_POST['jctotal']."</p>";
$time = date ("h:i A"); 
$date = date ("l, F jS, Y");
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: inquiry@diysoakwells.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: noreply@diysoakwells.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$emaile = $_POST['emaile'];
$textbox = $_POST['textbox'];
$text = "<html><body><p><b>Message:</b>\n$textbox</p><p>This form was submitted on Your Web Site on \n $date at\n $time</p><p><b>Customers Email Address:</b> $emaile</p><p><b>Customers Name:</b> $name </p><p><b>Customers Phone Number:</b> $phone </p></html>    </body>";
$body = $text . $jcitems;
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
Header('Location: ../form-accepted.php');
?>
```

Comment: Hi I'm back and having another go at this issue. Still havent solved it! Heres the code, the email arrives at diysoakwells@hotmail.com but not at the address of $emaile from the form input.

Answer (score 1):

What your doing is not what you want to do. Concatenating two strings in PHP is done with the . not the , so the correct syntax is:

```
$to      = 'diysoakwells@hotmail.com'.", ".$emaile;
```

or simply

```
$to      = "diysoakwells@hotmail.com, $emaile";
```

That's assuming that the code in charge of sending the email uses php's `mail()` function, which allows multiple emails in the $to argument. If that doesn't work, I can't be of more use without seeing the actual code.

Comment: thankyou I have tried this but do not recieve an email from $emaile?

Answer (score 1):

The 'to' field on emails accepts a string, with the email address comma-separated.

```
$to = 'diysoakwell@hotmail.com, ' . $emaile;
```

should do the trick.

You should check the email address that they provide is formatted as an email address, and it would be a good idea to have a CAPTCHA to prevent automated bots from using your form as a spamming tool.

Comment: PHP's syntax is influenced by Perl, and . is the string concatenation operator in Perl. Although in this particular case you could concatenate the two emails with the plus sign, it's not recommended to avoid unwanted effects since PHP is a loosely type language you could end up getting the mathematical result instead of the concatenated string.

Comment: tried this method and i get no errors, the email is sent to the string address but nothing turning up at the variable address

Comment: Did you just change the `$to` line in the code above, or did you move it as well?

Comment: I just changed it from `$to      = 'diysoakwells@hotmail.com';` to `$to = 'diysoakwell@hotmail.com, ' . $emaile;
`

Comment: its posting $emaile as part of $subject but wont work for Cc or the method you described.  I dont get it!

Comment: Does it work if the `$to` variable has **only** the variable email address? i.e. `$to = $emaile;`.
[I'm assuming that `$emaile` has been set by the time you set `$to` (it hasn't in the code sample above)]

Answer (score 1):

If you use php [mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) you can send copy by specifying additional headers like that:

```
$headers = 'Cc: '.$emaile;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: thanks for the comments guys, ill try a few of the suggestions now.

Comment: same result here, no mail turning up from the input address variable?