# Sending form data to my email address and address entered in form by user

Tags: php, forms, email

Hi I asked this question a year ago but couldnt solve it and am now having another go.

link to the original question:

[Send email to address from form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516965/send-email-to-address-from-form-input)

I need to send the form data from my form to the specified address 'diysoakwells@hotmail.com' and also the email address from the form field which is assigned the variable $emaile. As it is the email arrives at diysoakwells@hotmail.com but not the variable address ($emaile). I cant understand why but it is definitely picking up the form data as it has all the details included in the email when I receive it at diysoakwells@hotmail.com. I basically want a copy of the order sent to the user as well as myself.

```
<?php
include_once("wsp_captcha.php");

if(WSP_CheckImageCode() != "OK") {
header('location:/form-rejected.php');
die();
}

$subject = 'Order Inquiry';
$jcitems = " <p><b>ORDER:</b></p><p> " . $_POST['jcitems']."<p/>" . "<p><b>Total:</b> $" . $_POST['jctotal']."</p>";
$time = date ("h:i A"); 
$date = date ("l, F jS, Y");
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: inquiry@DIYSoakwells.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: noreply@diysoakwells.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$emaile = $_POST['emaile'];
$textbox = $_POST['textbox'];
$to = "diysoakwells@hotmail.com,$emaile";
$text = "<html><body><p>This form was submitted on Your Web Site on \n $date at\n $time</p><p><b>Message:</b>\n$textbox</p><p><b>Customers Email Address:</b> $emaile</p><p><b>Customers Name:</b> $name </p><p><b>Customers Phone Number:</b> $phone </p></html></body>";
$body = $text . $jcitems;
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
Header('Location: ../form-accepted.php');
?>
```

Please help if you can I will be monitoring this for the next few days. Open to suggestions/explanations!!!

Comment: Use a semi-colon instead of a comma between the email addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$to = "diysoakwells@hotmail.com;" . filter_var($emaile, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

You may also want to try this....

```
$to = "diysoakwells@hotmail.com;<" . filter_var($emaile, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) . ">";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the email comes through but goes to the spam folder, will need to look into how to avoid that.